# Laravel 10 ORM: Fetching Promoted Accounts with History Count Less than Plan Target

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I have three database tables in my project: **promoted_account_plans**, **promoted_accounts**, and **promoted_account_histories**. The structure and relationships are as follows:

**Table: promoted_account_plans (id, name, target)**

id (Primary Key)
name
target

**Table: promoted_accounts (id, name, promoted_account_plan_id)**

id (Primary Key)
name
promoted_account_plan_id (Foreign Key referencing promoted_account_plans.id)

**Table: promoted_account_histories (id, name, promoted_account_id)**

id (Primary Key)
name
promoted_account_id (Foreign Key referencing promoted_accounts.id)

**The relationships between the tables are as follows:**

**PromotedAccount** belongs to **PromotedAccountPlan**.
**PromotedAccount** has many **PromotedAccountHistory records**.

I need help with Laravel ORM to fetch data from the **PromotedAccount** table where the count of related **PromotedAccountHistory** records is less than the **PromotedAccountPlan** target.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relationships in the PromotedAccount model exist. e.g:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PromotedAccount extends Model
{
    public function accountPlan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PromotedAccountPlan::class, 'promoted_account_plan_id');
    }

    public function accountHistories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PromotedAccountHistory::class, 'promoted_account_id');
    }
}
```

Then to filter the PromotedAccount records based on the count of related PromotedAccountHistory records should be along these lines:

```
use App\Models\PromotedAccount;

$accounts = PromotedAccount::whereHas('accountHistories', function ($query) {
    $query->groupBy('promoted_account_id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) < promoted_account_plans.target');
})->get();
```

---

In response to "column not found" error

Seems that the promoted_account_plans.target column is not available in the subquery formed by the whereHas method. If this is the case, you should be able to join the promoted_account_plans table to the promoted_account_histories table through the promoted_accounts table. e.g:

```
use App\Models\PromotedAccount;

$accounts = PromotedAccount::whereHas('accountHistories', function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('promoted_account_histories.promoted_account_id, COUNT(*) as histories_count')
        ->join('promoted_accounts', 'promoted_accounts.id', '=', 'promoted_account_histories.promoted_account_id')
        ->join('promoted_account_plans', 'promoted_account_plans.id', '=', 'promoted_accounts.promoted_account_plan_id')
        ->groupBy('promoted_account_histories.promoted_account_id', 'promoted_account_plans.target')
        ->havingRaw('histories_count < promoted_account_plans.target');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but get error column not found promoted_account_plans.target

Comment: that's what you have said exists in that table "Table: promoted_account_plans (id, name, **target**)" if "column not found" then I'm not accountable for that. Show your model code that covers these tables in the question **&** always provide **complete** error messages

Comment: I have tried another way to run the query - if this doesn't work I am out of ideas until more is knowm about the model you are using.